# The paragraph is not moving or taking any property at all

Tags: html, css

The paragraph "See more" doesn't move, it just stays in it initial position. I indicated : top: 270px and left 100px but nothing. The rest of the code is working, also if I try to give that paragraph the same color from the css file it returns to black.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image.png" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Prism</title>
</head>

<body background="wallpaper.png">

<p id="More" style="color: #6441a5">See more</p>


<form action="D:\Prism\login\login.html">
    <input type="image" id="Buton" src="buton.png" alt="submit">
</form>
<div id="Trending">

        <p>Trending</p>
</div>



<div id="firstsec">
</div>

<div id="New">

      <p>New</p>

</div>

<div id="secondsec">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And the important part of the css :

```
 #More {
    font-size: larger;
    top: 270px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You need to add additional style of position - value as absolute, relative.

Comment: Please can you change the title of the question to something a little less generic?

Comment: For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/yxybx4nt/1/

Comment: I tried and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting position manually using left and right css properties, but if you want to set position relatively or fixed then you have to set css property either absolute or fixed.

if see more is relative to parent then.

```
#More {
    position:absolute;
    font-size: larger;
    top: 270px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

If see more is fixed position in browser.

```
#More {
    position:fixed;
    font-size: larger;
    top: 270px;
    left: 100px;
}
```